# Safari javascript null is not an object

Tags: javascript, safari

Having some issues with my sliding nav in safari. Basically it just doesn't work. In the inspector panel it is returning the error:

"TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById("contracted-menu").style')

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Cuttsy+Cuttsy | How we work</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/fonts/fonts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/media.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script src="js/menu.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

    <script>

    if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 769px)").matches) {
      function openNav() {
        document.getElementById("expanded-menu").style.marginLeft = "0";
        document.getElementById("contracted-menu").style.marginLeft = "-75px";
      }
      function closeNav() {
        document.getElementById("expanded-menu").style.marginLeft = "-230px";
        document.getElementById("contracted-menu").style.marginLeft = "0";
      }
    } else if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 768px)").matches){
      function openNav() {
        document.getElementById("expanded-menu").style.marginTop = "0";
        document.getElementById("contracted-menu").style.marginTop = "-75px";
      }
      function closeNav() {
        document.getElementById("expanded-menu").style.marginTop = "-100vh";
        document.getElementById("contracted-menu").style.marginTop = "0";
      }
    }


    </script>


  </head>
  <body>


    <!-- ======================
    ========== MENU ===========
    ======================= -->

      <div class="expanded-menu" id="expanded-menu">
        <!-- MENU -->
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">
            <img src="images/Backarrow.png" alt="back arrow">
          </a>
          <a href="index.html">
            <img src="images/Cuttsy+Cuttsy_Logo_Square_RGB.png" class="logo" alt="cuttsy and cuttsy logo">
          </a>
          <a href="who-we-are.html">who we are</a>
          <img src="images/Line.png" class="menu-line" alt="line">
          <a href="how-we-work.html">how we work</a>
          <img src="images/Line.png" class="menu-line" alt="line">
          <a href="what-we-do.html">what we do</a>
          <img src="images/Line.png" class="menu-line" alt="line">
          <a href="who-we-do-it-for.html">who we do it for</a>
          <img src="images/Line.png" class="menu-line" alt="line">
          <a href="cuttings.html">cuttings</a>
          <img src="images/Line.png" class="menu-line" alt="line">
          <a href="join-us.html">join us</a>
          <img src="images/Line.png" class="menu-line" alt="line">
          <a href="contact.html">contact</a>
        <div class="socialmedia">
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/cuttsyandcuttsy/" target="_blank">
            <img src="images/social-media-icons/Facebook.png" alt="facebook logo">
          </a>
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/cuttsyandcuttsy/?hl=en" target="_blank">
            <img src="images/social-media-icons/Instagram.png" alt="instagram logo">
          </a>
          <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/2128917/" target="_blank">
            <img src="images/social-media-icons/Linkedin.png" alt="linkedin logo">
          </a>
          <a href="https://twitter.com/cuttsyandcuttsy" target="_blank">
            <img src="images/social-media-icons/Twitter.png" alt="twitter logo">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="privacy">
          <p><a href="privacy.html">Privacy policy</a></p>
          <p>&copy; Cuttsy+Cuttsy 2018</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- ======================
      ======= SMALL MENU ========
      ======================= -->

      <div class="contracted-menu" id="contracted-menu">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openNav()">
          <img src="images/nav-icons/menu.png"  class="burger" alt="open menu">
        </a>
        <div class="menu-icons">
          <a href="who-we-are.html">
            <img src="images/nav-icons/Who-we-are.png" alt="who we are">
          </a>
          <a href="how-we-work.html">
            <img src="images/nav-icons/How-we-work.png" alt="how we work">
          </a>
          <a href="what-we-do.html">
            <img src="images/nav-icons/What-we-do.png" alt="what we do">
          </a>
          <a href="who-we-do-it-for.html">
            <img src="images/nav-icons/who-we-do-it-for.png" alt="who we do it for">
          </a>
          <a href="cuttings.html">
            <img src="images/nav-icons/cuttings.png" alt="cuttings">
          </a>
          <a href="join-us.html">
            <img src="images/nav-icons/join.png" alt="join us">
          </a>
          <a href="contact.html">
            <img src="images/nav-icons/contact.png" alt="contact us">
          </a>

          <div class="socialmedia-sm">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/cuttsyandcuttsy/" target="_blank">
              <img src="images/social-media-icons/Facebook.png" class="sm-small" alt="facebook logo">
            </a>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/cuttsyandcuttsy/?hl=en" target="_blank">
              <img src="images/social-media-icons/Instagram.png" class="sm-small" alt="instagram logo">
            </a>
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/2128917/" target="_blank">
              <img src="images/social-media-icons/Linkedin.png" class="sm-small" alt="linkedin logo">
            </a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/cuttsyandcuttsy" target="_blank">
              <img src="images/social-media-icons/Twitter.png" class="sm-small" alt="twitter logo">
            </a>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- ======================
      ========= CONTENT =========
      ======================= -->
    <div class="webcontent">
      <div id="main">
        <div>
          <div class="row" class="col-sm-12">
            <h1>How we work.</h1>
            <p class="intro">At Cuttsy and Cuttsy, we never lose sight of what really matters – people. That’s why we pride ourselves on developing close and mutually respectful relationships with our clients. It’s why we constantly keep in mind what the patient or end-user really needs to know. And it’s why we work hard to maintain an award-winning culture of professional development to attract the very best people we can to join our team.</p>
          </div>

          <div class="secNav">
            <ul>
              <a href="how-we-work.html"><li class="subButton">Emotional Intelligence</li></a>
              <a href="co-create.html"><li class="subButton">Co+Create</li></a>
              <a href="health-literacy.html"><li class="subButton">Health Literacy</li></a>
            </ul>
            <ul class="secNav-level2">
              <a href="compliance.html"><li class="subButton">Compliance</li></a>
              <a href="CSR.html"><li class="subButton">CSR</li></a>
            </ul>

          </div>


          <div class="row">
            <hr class="dividingline">
            <h2>Emotional Intelligence</h2>

            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <p id="intro-body">Emotional Intelligence (EI) is the capability of individuals to recognise their own and other people&rsquo;s emotions and use emotional information to guide thinking and behaviour.</p>
              <p class="body-copy">
              One of our guiding principles is the power of EI. By guiding our thinking and behaviour, EI helps us to build meaningful and impactful connections in our communications.</p>

              <h3>EI guides what we do</h3>
              <img src="images/emotional-intelligence.png" class="bodyimg">
              <hr class="dividingline">
              <img src="images/reason-emotion.png" class="bodyimg">

              <p class="body-copy" style="padding-top:30px;">
              If you would like to find out more about how we use EI to guide our processes, <a href="#">let’s talk.</a></p>

            </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>




  </body>

  <footer class="global-footer">
    <div class="footer-nav col-sm-10">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <ul>
          <a href="index.html"><li>Home</li></a>
          <a href="who-we-are.html"><li>Who we are</li></a>
          <a href="team.html"><li>Meet the Team</li></a>
          <a href="CPD.html"><li>CPD</li></a>
          <a href="How-we-work.html"><li>How we work</li></a>
          <a href="co-create.html"><li>Co+Create</li></a>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <ul>
          <a href="health-literacy.html"><li>Health Literacy</li></a>
          <a href="compliance.html"><li>Compliance</li></a>
          <a href="CSR.html"><li>CSR</li></a>
          <a href="what-we-do.html"><li>What we do</li></a>
          <a href="books.html"><li>Books</li></a>
          <a href="who-we-do-it-for.html"><li>Who we do it for</li></a>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <ul>
          <a href="cuttings.html"><li>Cuttings</li></a>
          <a href="join-us.html"><li>Join us</li></a>
          <a href="contact.html"><li>Contact</li></a>
          <a href="privacy.html"><li>Privacy policy</li></a>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</html>
```

Anyone have any ideas? It's the code between the script tags that doesn't want to work.

Comment: try putting the script before `</html>` at the very end.

Comment: Nope, no luck - still returning the same error.

Comment: Your if condition should be inside the function

Answer (score 1):

assign your functions to variables like this:

```
<script>

if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 769px)").matches) {
    var openNav = function() {
        document.getElementById("expanded-menu").style.marginLeft = "0";
        document.getElementById("contracted-menu").style.marginLeft = "-75px";
    }
    var closeNav = function() {
        document.getElementById("expanded-menu").style.marginLeft = "-230px";
        document.getElementById("contracted-menu").style.marginLeft = "0";
    }
} else if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 768px)").matches){
    var openNav = function() {
        document.getElementById("expanded-menu").style.marginTop = "0";
        document.getElementById("contracted-menu").style.marginTop = "-75px";
    }
    var closeNav = function() {
        document.getElementById("expanded-menu").style.marginTop = "-100vh";
        document.getElementById("contracted-menu").style.marginTop = "0";
    }
}


</script>
```